# How to bypass lines matching some regexp, when searching forward

Tags: regular-expressions, search, match-data

I've written the following function to go from an error line to the next one:

```
(defconst mylog-mode-error-regexp
  "\\(\\[ERROR\\]\\|rule did fail\\)"
  "Regexp to recognize errors in my log file.")

(defun mylog-mode-next-error ()
  "Go to next error."
  (interactive)
  (let ((case-fold-search nil))
    (search-forward-regexp mylog-mode-error-regexp)
    (narrow-to-region 1 (line-end-position))
    (setq current-count (mylog-mode-count-errors))
    (widen)
    (message "Error %d/%d" current-count (mylog-mode-count-errors))))
```

I'd like to skip some lines, the ones matching:

```
[ERROR][2018-05-29 07:39:25,149][Authenticated] - [Page [/login.html] is not allowed]
```

… as those errors aren't real errors -- which I have to debug.

How could I do that?

Comment: Don't count them, in your `mylog-mode-count-errors`?

Comment: @Drew, that's another valid point, they should not be counted at all. The thing is I can't describe what must be counted, I only can describe what must NOT be counted (the line above). I should count all matches, and then substract the specific count that matches the above line, then?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Obviously the trivial option is to change your regexp so that only matches things you want it to match.

I believe you're asking how to test the match results, though.  As with any search, `(search-forward-regexp mylog-mode-error-regexp)` produces match data which you can easily use to perform further processing on what the search found.  Exactly how you do that is up to you, and you should read <kbd>C-h</kbd><kbd>i</kbd><kbd>g</kbd> `(elisp)Match Data`

Here's one possible approach, which keeps searching until `(this-match-is-valid)` is true.

```el
(while (and (search-forward-regexp mylog-mode-error-regexp)
            (save-excursion
              (save-restriction
                (narrow-to-region (match-beginning 0) (match-end 0))
                (goto-char (point-min))
                (not (this-match-is-valid))))))
;; do things with the valid match
```

Comment: IIUC, the matched data here will be the [ERROR] keyword only.  How can I write the this-match-is-valid function to see if it matches some regexp?  There must be a function, but I don't find it. Regarding the narrowing, I guess I would narrow between beginning of line and end of line, so that's OK. Only the matching part is missing now. Thanks for your info!

Comment: You'll probably find the `looking-at` function useful.

Comment: And of course if the narrowing isn't useful to you, don't do it.  There's no *need* to narrow here -- it's just an example of something you *could* do to assist with analysing the match.

Comment: looking-at is certainly the function I was missing. And, of course, I agree about the narrowing… Thanks a lot!